# iTunesConnect: cannot transfer app because of "You must turn off TestFlight beta testing for the app that you want to transfer"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

Below you can see that testing for external testers are turned off:
[image]

same for internal testing:

[image]

but when I transfer app, one of the criterias are not met:

[image]

Why?

Comment: You've followed exact steps for disabling testflight beta as per this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html Please ask Apple for the resolution. this seems to be a bug in iTunes Connect.

Comment: I wonder when this will be fixed or someone finds out workaround...

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been resolved?

Comment: Did you found any solution yet ??

Comment: As of Monday, May 22, 2017 there is still no solution for this problem!  Apparently, it's been an issue on Apple's end for over a year.  You can follow this thread for more updates.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28646

Comment: i solved it clearing all fields, removing all testers (internal and externals) and expiring all builds

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same issue, resolved by removing all Tester and Build from the TestFlight as discussed above also (!important) remove everything fields at the App Information - Test Information.

Comment: For me, I should remove about all of the localized Test Information as well as all testers and test binary.

Comment: it really saved me. Thanks! mainly we just need to remove all the information from the TestFlight tab.

Comment: Removing all fields in the test information page worked for me. Thanx

Answer (score 12):

For me it was localised test descriptions. Make sure you check that drop down list on the right and clear out info for all languages. 
[image]

Answer (score 12):

I just solved the transfer issue, you just need to expire your build from tester by following the steps below. and then app will available for transfer..

open your app and click on testflight then click on the icon of your app as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

The click on expire build.
[image]

Now you can transfer your app :)

Comment: It worked for me. If you have any app info in test flights remove that also

Comment: Yeah, just now it is working for me too. Just expire all builds along with remove all information text

Answer (score 10):

I've search for a long time and to me this worked:

1. Clean all builds inside: **My Apps --> App Name --> TestFlight**
2. Go to: **Itunes Connect --> Users and Roles --> Tab "TestFlight Beta Testers"** and click in the name from another user that isn't you.
3. Save.
4. Go back to the App in Itunes Connect: **"Itunes Connect --> App Name --> Transfer App"** and attempt to transfer again by clicking in "Transfer App".

To me this works. Hope help someone.

Comment: this worked for me, however I have to logout and log back in again

Answer (score 7):

i had the same issue i deleted (mark expired) all the versions of app testing version in App **TestFlight** section and done the trick for me ;) attach is the screen shot of activity. 
[image]

Comment: i have expired all the build, still its not working.

Comment: i have done two things deleted all beta testers secondly marked expired all build version do the trick for me.

Comment: @UmarFarooq if we delete all the builds from testflight, how come we can transfer the app,Please can you elaborate the scenario.

Comment: i expanded version drop down and mark the all previous version expired.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this for an entire day, I tried everything and finally found another workaround:

1) Expire all the builds

2) Delete all testers

3) Clear all the informations in the Testflight tab

4) Delete all langages except the main one

And finally the step which fixed the Testflight criteria for us

**5) Create a new app version (no need to submit or even edit it)**

now you check transfer.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible reason:

When you delete all test information from TestFlight, make sure you delete it for **every language**.
In the testinformation page, select every localised language and check if the form is empty.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question, but it still bugs people to this day.

So the solution here, after you have removed all the testers, and expired all builds, go to **TestFlight** > **Test Information** and clear all the fields.

Also make sure you delete any localization you might have there. Give it 5 minutes, after which transfering will be possible.

[image]

Comment: This is so stupid. It actually worked. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, I know, it has bugged me for the second time, after I actually forgot what I've done the first time when I transferred an app ..

Comment: Alelouia !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is going to help,

Check Users and Roles > TestFlight Beta Testers

[image]

Do you have a tester who is testing the app that you want to transfer?

Comment: Yes, but since I checked "Not available for testing" it should no matter, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks it's help me :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue and I'm currently getting from Apple "our engineering team is still working diligently to have this resolved for you". I have been supplied with a workaround:

1. Enable TestFlight by adding a tester to a build
2. Then deactivate the build, by turning off TestFlight beta testing
3. Attempt to transfer again

unfortunately, I still haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I contacted Apple too and after few weeks of communicating, they sent me this... It didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

We found that in addition to the other answers here, logging out and logging back in to iTunesConnect allowed us to continue after it was saying TestFlight was still enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, going inside tranferring app console multiple times automatically fixed the issue and started showing all criteria as met.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same step as @Imran Iqbal answer, if your app is Sign-in Required, uncheck Sign-in Required also, like:
[image]

then, you can transfer app.

Comment: It worked for me. If it is not checked, first check it and then un check it again. Then save

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same problem and could not solve it. The good news: After contacting Apple, they have confirmed a bug and they're working on a solutions. Apple confirmed also, that many developers ran into this.

Got that workaround from the support (that did not work for me):

**1.** Enable TestFlight by adding a tester to a build

**2.** Then deactivate the build, by turning off TestFlight beta testing

**3.** Attempt to transfer again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is being done on purpose for new apps.
Now, A newly created app CANNOT be transferred into an account, until 14 - 21 days have passed.
An expiration period.

Answer (score 0):

**First, You must remove all build and user from TestFlight of that app.** After its looks like below.

If you still not match last criteria than Sign Out and login again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating new app version did it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tricky solution is to enable testing again, add some tester in. The visit the TestFlight and under test flight users, you will see old active test flight users. Simple delete them.