# How to remove iTunes Connect TestFlight "Beta App Review Information" to allow app transfer

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm attempting to transfer an app to a different user account in iTunes Connect and I cannot delete the information in the TestFlight > Test Information > Beta App Review Information > Contact Information section. When I clear the fields and click the save button, the information reappears. Developer console shows a 200 response and appropriate parameters sent to Apple:

[image]

When I attempt to transfer, I get a popup telling my I need to remove this information to proceed with transfer:

[image: iTunes Connect]

So I must clear the fields to proceed, but the fields are un-clearable. I'm stuck. Does a workaround exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iTunesConnect: cannot transfer app because of "You must turn off TestFlight beta testing for the app that you want to transfer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906771/itunesconnect-cannot-transfer-app-because-of-you-must-turn-off-testflight-beta)

Comment: @MohitKumar nope. I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple pushed a new version somewhere and now I can clear the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for an entire week, I tried everything and finally found another workaround:

1) Upload new build

2) Clear all the informations in the Testflight tab

3) Expire the build

4) Log in and log out

Good Luck!